# Ruby on rails: app renders the partial very beginning not when user reaches the end of the page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

below is my code

```
$(window).scroll(function()
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
        {
            $.ajax({
            success: function(html)
            {
                if(html)
                {
                    $("div.new_load").html("<%= escape_javascript (render :partial => 'new_load') %>");
                }else
                {
                    $('new_load').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                }
            }
            });
        }
    });
```

Now what happens is, when the page load along with other partials, the `new_load` partial loads as well. But according to my js it should render when the reached the bottom. That being said, how do I make my app render partial as per my js?

***Or in short I want the code in `new_load partial` only to get executed when the user scrolls down. Is there a way to do that ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The partial will be rendered when the page is served from the server and added to .new_load when your Javascript wants. You will have to get the contents using Ajax if you want to have full control of the timeline of events.

Comment: well the thing is , i want the code in `new_load partial` only to get executed when the user scrolls down. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: That's what I meant, by using Ajax to retrieve the contents at that point of time. So instead of a partial, create a route for it, serve it with no layout and use http://api.jquery.com/load/ (or similar) to retreive the content.

Comment: actually the code that is present is basically instance variables from and methods from my controller. I just cant append all the code i guess. so is there another way to do it?

Comment: Hard to tell without the code. If it's mostly instance variables, why not render that form the beginning? What will change from there to the point the user scrolls? I will only use AJAX (and probably $.getJSON) to retrieve values that changed since the initial load.

Comment: This is the part that i need to render - http://pastebin.com/eEqZNCUb . When the page load the first round of the data loads, which is already set. Now, every time the user reaches the end of the page, i want the app to reload the code in the partial so new data is fetched with the `@second_round` instance variable which is already set accordingly in the controllers.

Comment: But `@second_round` was already set, so there is no new data and it doesn't make sense to delay the rendering of this partial. Conversations are discouraged on Stack Overflow. My conclusion: if you want new data use `$.load` or `$.getJSON`, if not, just render the partial.